# ng-click not firing with django/angular

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I have a template which is rendered by Django, and am trying to add some js behavior with angular. It's a pain.

here's the form. The `ng_controller` is a django context variable, set by my view.

```
<form method="POST" action="#"  ng-controller="{{ ng_controller }}" >

  <a href="#" ng-click="search('{% url 'appname:search' %}')" class="button">Search</a>
  <a href="#" ng-click="add()" class="button">Add</a>


<div class="small-12 large-4 columns content-box">
 <h4>Search Results</h4>
  <div class="small-12.large4" id="search_results" >

</div>
```

the clicking the Search button works as expected, here's the function

```
search: (search_url) =>
  console.log "Searching..."
  success = (result) ->
     $("#search_results").replaceWith(result.data)

  error = (result) ->
     console.log "Error: #{result}"

  url = "#{search_url}/?#{form_data}"
  @$http.get(url).then(success, error)
```

The problem is that result.data, which is correctly swapped out in the #search_results element contains the `ng-click` directives that don't fire

```
 <a href="#" ng-click="foo()" class="button" >Do Foo</a>
 <a href="#" ng-click="console.log('foo');" class="button">Log Foo</a>
```

When those elements are there (after clicking search) they do nothing except jump to the top of the page, as per the anchor element. No errors or anything. (For the sake of argument, `foo()` would just call `console.log 'foo'`

My suspicion is that because these directives are added after the page load, they're not actually wired up by angular. So is that correct? And if that's the problem, how can I get them to compile the directives in this scheme, or otherwise get the behavior I'm looking for? I understand that there's issues with manipulating the DOM via jQuery while using Angular, so I'd be grateful for suggestions to tackle the problem by making the replacement code more idiomatic, so long as it can do so by an AJAX request to a Django endpoint.

Comment: Whenever you mix Angular with jQuery, expect to run into problems. But specifically, in your case, it doesn't look like the `result.data` has any Angular expressions - so it should have worked. Can you check the rendered page (just before you click the button) and see if you have a single `<div id="search_results">`

Comment: There is a single `<div id="search_results"></div>` in the pre-search rendered page. The `result.data` that gets swapped out does have the `ng-click` directives--are these not angular expressions? I'm new to angular and we're certainly not using it in its intended manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was correct, and the results were not compiled. It was a matter of explicitly compiling the results.

the success callback from above is replaced with this:

```
success = (result) =>
     search_results = $(result.data)
     $("#search_results").replaceWith(search_results)
     @$compile(search_results)(@$scope)
```

I also injected the $compile provider into the controller class.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. Yes, injecting HTML with Angular expressions/directives would not work without compiling - you are right. I thought originally that no content was added to `search_results` - not that it wasn't firing.